# android studio dark blue-green theme

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.1

How to set my Android Studio IDE theme as seen in the image:
[Android Developer theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uafx.png)

[image]

I saw such kind of theme while watching youtube android developer material design tutorial. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5-ntYM_2UY)

Answer (score 1):

Goto File-> Settings -> Appearance -> Themes and choose **Dracula**.

Comment: I have already done that but i am not able to get tag name and attributes colors as shown in the image. I don't want to set individually each and every tag to color and for every language which is heavy job. so can you suggest where do i get such kind of theme as shown in the image.